# Only getting null from API Kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin

I'm making an android app using Kotlin where one of the features are getting a random drink from an API called The CocktailDB. But when I'm prompting the drink and its attributes it only says null. How to solve this?
My Drink class:

```
package com.example.drinkify.uhm

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

class Drink {
    @SerializedName("idDrink")
     val idDrink: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrink")
     val strDrink: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrinkAlternate")
     val strDrinkAlternate: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrinkES")
     val strDrinkES: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrinkDE")
     val strDrinkDE: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrinkFR")
     val strDrinkFR: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrinkZH-HANS")
     val strDrinkZHHANS: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrinkZH-HANT")
     val strDrinkZHHANT: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strTags")
     val strTags: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strVideo")
     val strVideo: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strCategory")
     val strCategory: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIBA")
     val strIBA: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strAlcoholic")
     val strAlcoholic: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strGlass")
     val strGlass: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strInstructions")
     val strInstructions: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strInstructionsES")
     val strInstructionsES: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strInstructionsDE")
     val strInstructionsDE: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strInstructionsFR")
     val strInstructionsFR: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strInstructionsZH-HANS")
     val strInstructionsZHHANS: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strInstructionsZH-HANT")
     val strInstructionsZHHANT: Any? = null

    @SerializedName("strDrinkThumb")
     val strDrinkThumb: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient1")
     val strIngredient1: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient2")
     val strIngredient2: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient3")
     val strIngredient3: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient4")
     val strIngredient4: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient5")
     val strIngredient5: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient6")
     val strIngredient6: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient7")
     val strIngredient7: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient8")
     val strIngredient8: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient9")
     val strIngredient9: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient10")
     val strIngredient10: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient11")
     val strIngredient11: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient12")
     val strIngredient12: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient13")
     val strIngredient13: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient14")
     val strIngredient14: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strIngredient15")
     val strIngredient15: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure1")
     val strMeasure1: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure2")
     val strMeasure2: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure3")
     val strMeasure3: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure4")
     val strMeasure4: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure5")
     val strMeasure5: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure6")
     val strMeasure6: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure7")
     val strMeasure7: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure8")
     val strMeasure8: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure9")
     val strMeasure9: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure10")
     val strMeasure10: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure11")
     val strMeasure11: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure12")
     val strMeasure12: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure13")
     val strMeasure13: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure14")
     val strMeasure14: String? = null

    @SerializedName("strMeasure15")
     val strMeasure15: String? = null

    @SerializedName("dateModified")
     val dateModified: String? = null

}
```

The interface:

```
package com.example.drinkify.ui

import com.example.drinkify.uhm.Drink
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface RandomDrinkAPI {
    @get:GET("random.php")
    val drinks: Call<Drink>

}
```

And lastly the activity:

```
package com.example.drinkify.ui

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.drinkify.R
import com.example.drinkify.uhm.Drink
import com.example.drinkify.uhm.Post
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory



class RandomizeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var textViewResult: TextView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_randomize)

        textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result)

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val randomDrinkApi: RandomDrinkAPI = retrofit.create(RandomDrinkAPI::class.java)
        val call = randomDrinkApi.drinks
        call.enqueue(object: Callback<Drink> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Drink>, response: Response<Drink>) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                    textViewResult?.setText("Code: " + response.code())
                    return
                }

                val drink = response.body()!!

                    var content = ""
                    content += """
                        Drink ${drink.strDrink}
                        
                        """.trimIndent()
                    content += """
                        Category ${drink.strCategory}
                        
                        """.trimIndent()
                    content += """
                        Alcoholic ${drink.strAlcoholic}
                        
                        """.trimIndent()
                    content += """
                        Instructions ${drink.strInstructions}
                        
                        
                        """.trimIndent()
                    textViewResult?.append(content)


            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Drink>, t: Throwable) {
                textViewResult?.setText(t.message)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I've tried using other API's with this method and it has worked. Ive also tried changing it to a list e.g Call<List>, but then I got the error: "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the object returned by the api

```
{
    "drinks": [{
        "idDrink": "14860",
        "strDrink": "Talos Coffee",
        "strDrinkAlternate": null,
        "strTags": null,
        "strVideo": null,
        "strCategory": "Coffee \/ Tea",
        "strIBA": null,
        "strAlcoholic": "Alcoholic",
        "strGlass": "Brandy snifter",
        "strInstructions": "Add your GM and then add your coffee.",
        "strInstructionsES": null,
        "strInstructionsDE": "F\u00fcge deinen GM und dann deinen Kaffee hinzu.",
        "strInstructionsFR": null,
        "strInstructionsIT": "Aggiungi il Grand Marnier e poi aggiungi il tuo caff\u00e8.",
        "strInstructionsZH-HANS": null,
        "strInstructionsZH-HANT": null,
        "strDrinkThumb": "https:\/\/www.thecocktaildb.com\/images\/media\/drink\/rswqpy1441246518.jpg",
        "strIngredient1": "Grand Marnier",
        "strIngredient2": "Coffee",
        "strIngredient3": null,
        "strIngredient4": null,
        "strIngredient5": null,
        "strIngredient6": null,
        "strIngredient7": null,
        "strIngredient8": null,
        "strIngredient9": null,
        "strIngredient10": null,
        "strIngredient11": null,
        "strIngredient12": null,
        "strIngredient13": null,
        "strIngredient14": null,
        "strIngredient15": null,
        "strMeasure1": "3 parts ",
        "strMeasure2": "1 part ",
        "strMeasure3": null,
        "strMeasure4": null,
        "strMeasure5": null,
        "strMeasure6": null,
        "strMeasure7": null,
        "strMeasure8": null,
        "strMeasure9": null,
        "strMeasure10": null,
        "strMeasure11": null,
        "strMeasure12": null,
        "strMeasure13": null,
        "strMeasure14": null,
        "strMeasure15": null,
        "strImageSource": null,
        "strImageAttribution": null,
        "strCreativeCommonsConfirmed": "No",
        "dateModified": "2015-09-03 03:15:18"
    }]
}
```

For gson to understand and deserialize this object, you will need to create another class.

```
    data class DrinkHolder(
          @SerializedName("drinks")   
          val drink: List<Drink>
    )
```

Now you this new class to the call: Call